# VBA code to protect sheets and show/hide buttons

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a simple VBA code running every time my Excel file opens, and it worked fine for years. Since several weeks tho it stopped working. The purpose is for specific cells on every sheets to be locked every time the Excel file is opened, and to have a button that if I click on unlocks everything at once.

Now, when I open the Ecxel file I get this message:

[image]

It's in French and means: Compilation error, member method or data couldn't be found

Then I say OK and it opens the debug mode:
[image]

Finally, when I go the sheet36 (which is my summary page where the button to unlock sheets appear) and click on the button that unprotect all sheets, I enter the password and get an 1004 error:
[image]

In English: Execution error '1004': Invalid password. Verify that the CAPSLOCK key is not activated and that you are using the correct case.

Also the code to protect and unprotect all my sheets seem to have a problem, because the sheets are not protected when I first open the file. Here is the code: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itOrA.jpg)

Specific cells on all sheets are supposed to be locked when we open the file, and there is one button on sheet36 which unlocks everything with a password. But as off now only the "unprotect button" appears on sheet36.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The first mistake is that, you have not declared the `sh` variable & the second if you could clear what is `Feuil36` !! ☺

Comment: The yellow highlighted line is not erroneous line, it's the line to be executed, but the sub must be compiled first. The compilation fails because `CommandButton2` in sheet `Feuil36` can not be found.

Comment: OK thank you both, so I guess I'm a total noob at VBA because I don't understand what you recommand me to do... what should I do exactly to fix this?

Comment: Learn VBa. I know that sounds like a naff answer but start now. Also, are you sure it's the right password

Comment: @Johanna,, you are getting an error because the **Command Syntax** is wrong. Check my post,  I've suggested few methods along with correct way (command syntax) to  hide & unhide the Button.

Answer (score 0):

*To get rid from the error you need to do the followings:*

```
Sheets("Feuil36").Shapes("CommandButton2").Visible = False
```

**How it works:**

1. Press `Alt+F11` to open VB editor.
2. From the **View Menu** find & Click 
   **Immediate Window**.
3. Either write or `Copy & Paste` above written 
   code in `Immediate Window` and finish with 
   `Enter.`

**Or**

*You can use Macro also.*

```
Sub ButtonHideUnHide()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = feuil36
With ws
    .Shapes("CommandButton2").Visible = msoFalse
    .Shapes("CommandButton1").Visible = msoTrue

End With
End Sub
```

**Note:** Event, Sheet & Command Button names are editable.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, thank you for the code, although it doesn't seem to do the same thing. The password protection need to run by itself everytime the file opens. I should'nt need to click on the button to protect sheets. Also, even if I click on button1 to deprotect all my sheets, the button2 to protect them all never reappears. Button1 just stays there the all time. Any idea why?

Comment: @Johanna, the Screen Shot you have attached with the question is not about  PROTECTION,, the code reflects that you are trying to hide / un-hide the Command Buttons and nothing. You are getting an error because the Command Syntax in wrong and that's what I've shown through my answer. Better you edit the Question and write exactly what you need !!  ☺

Comment: Rajesh, thank you for your answer. So I edited the text of my post by adding the code to protect and unprotect the file. Do you see something wrong in it? It doesn't run when I open the file as it was doing before.

Comment: @Johanna, yes your code does have few errors,,, 1. to make the command button visible or hide `ME.Commandbutton1`  gives error unless you have not defined `Me`   as Sheet. Normally `ME` use for `USER FORM`. 2. The way U r  trying to use command to  protect Sheet is wrong,, it should be `wSheet.Protect Password:="Secret"`.